# class selector doesn't work in a tooltip content loaded via AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am using a class name for all href links in my pages,
For example;

```
<a href="https://mysite.com" class="ajax">
```

And select that class to load content without refreshing the page,

```
$(".ajax").on('click',function() {
   event.preventDefault();
   return false;
   var t = $(this).attr("href");
   History.pushState(null, 'TEST', t);
});
```

BUT when i load content into the tooltip, that doesn't work.

I tried to add the code above in `document.ready` state into the loaded tooltip content but didn't work too.

How can i do it ?

Thanks

P.S : I am using Tipped plug-in for my all tooltip solutions.

Comment: Code after `return false` is not executed actually. Move it to be the latest statement in function and check if it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning false before the history function runs, preventDefault should be enough, but you will need an event, notice the "e" in the function(e):

```
$(document).on('click', '.ajax', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var t = $(this).attr("href");
    History.pushState(null, 'TEST', t);
});
```

Comment: History.js plugin documents it like that
    var History = window.History; // Note: We are using a capital H instead of a lower h

Comment: Ah, I see, then it's a plugin so you should use capital H, the native window.history is not with a capital H, changed it!

Comment: I tried. But links in the dynamically loaded content still refresh the page :S

Answer (score 1):

Once you `return false;`, your function immediately exits at that point.

Structure it like so:

```
$(".ajax").on('click',function() {
  History.pushState(null, 'TEST', $(this).attr("href"));

  return false;
});
```

Comment: tried this. but still doesnt work. it refreshes the page when i click the link on dynamically loaded content